# Dates change when passing from back end function to front end function

Tags: javascript, date, velo

Let me start off by apologizing for the length of this post but I want to be as verbose as possible as this issue is very interesting and weird.

I am rendering a date picker with room availability for resorts that my company manages. This is accomplished with two functions (one back end function and one front end function).

The back end function makes a request to an external API, formats the response into an array of date objects and returns the array.

The front end function calls the back end function and then pushes the response onto an object that renders the availability.

The array of date objects is not changed or mutated in any way after it is formatted by the back end function. Yet somehow the dates that are rendered on the front end are always one day before the date that is returned from the back end function.

I know that sounds confusing so let me clarify.

Here is the array of date objects that is returned from the back end function:
[correct dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwaSk.png)

Here is what is rendered to the date picker:
[Incorrect dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFbYD.png)

At first I was almost convinced that the date picker was just getting the dates wrong so I did a bit more digging and found out that the dates that are stored in the array are somehow changing as they are being passed back to the front end function.

Here is the code for the front end function that is applicable:

```
getAvailAsync(startDate, endDate, attributeId, resortId, room, resort, duration).then(response => {
            console.log("returned to front end", response.res.availability)
            response.res.error ? "" : repeaterData.push(response.res)
            $w("#resortsRepeater").data = repeaterData

            if(repeaterData.length > 12) {
                $w("#loadMore").show()
            }
            if(repeaterData.length > 0) {
                $w("#loadingStrip").collapse()
            }
        })
```

Here is what is logged to the console from the front end:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "Fri Jul 15 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Fri Jul 15 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "Sat Jul 16 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Sat Jul 16 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "Sun Jul 17 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Sun Jul 17 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "Mon Jul 18 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Mon Jul 18 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "Tue Jul 19 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Tue Jul 19 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "Tue Jul 26 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
    "endDate": "Tue Jul 26 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
  }
]
```

As you can see the first date is July 15th and the last date is July 26th.

Now here is the applicable code from the back end getAvailAsync function:

```
if(validAvail == undefined) {
                resolve({ res: {error: "No availability found"}})
            } else {
                console.log("Valid avail before passing to the front end", validAvail)
              validAvail.length > 0 
                ? 
                resolve({
                    res: {
                        ...resortInfo,
                        ...roomInfo,
                        availability: validAvail
                    }    
                })
                : resolve({
                    res: {error: "No availability found"}
                })  
            }
```

Here is what is logged to the console from the back end function:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-17T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-18T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-19T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

As you can see the first date is July 16th and the last date is July 27th.

What's more is every single date has been decremented by 1 somehow.

I am completely clueless as to why this is happening. The only thing that I can think of is that the back end function has a date object for the start date and end date after being returned from the API (see the first image where it says {"startDate": {$date: "2022-07-02...}, ...}

Could that somehow be messing up the date? And if so how do I resolve this?

Comment: It's just a timezone difference, they are the same time.

Comment: So then I need to either get rid of the timezone (does not seem possible without converting to a string; which I can not do) or I need to be able to enforce the same time zone when rendering to the screen somehow

Answer (score 0):

As pilchard mentioned this issue was related to the changing of time zones when the date object was passed to the front end and rendered to the screen. I just had to set the hour manually to noon using date.setHours(). This way the date was not changed when the timezone changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).